# geckodriver for many tests - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, geckodriver

Is it necessary to add a geckodriver every time I create another test? e.g :

```
public class JUnit4 {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "D:\\...\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.pl/");
        driver.close();
        }

   @Test
   public void test2() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "D:\\...\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.pl/");
    driver.close();
   }

}
```

The code above works.

If I insert a geckodriver before the test name it obviously does not work. I have tried to add geckodriver to system variables but it also does not work. I also watched how it would have done with @Before but also did not work.If I pull the driver before the tests then it is a mistake because first it must be geckodriver.

**Is there a way to use only once geckodriver despite many tests?**

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define it only once in @Before and make Web driver a global variable.

```
 public class JUnit4 {

 public WebDriver driver;

 @Before
    public void setup() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path of the geckodriver ");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
                  }
 @Test
public void test1() {
    driver.get("https://www.google.pl/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I know, it is really simple:

if you are in system variables just use ";" in path e.g

path1;path2;  and paste you path into system variables -> than you do not need to paste every time :

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "C:\...\geckodriver.exe");